# Как изменять значение переменной, зная поинтер?

Tags: delphi

Я нашел поинтер и его смещения для переменной в Cheat Engine:

[image: Адреса]

Как, зная эти данные изменять значение из программы на Delphi?

Я сделал поиск PID, Process Handle. Если использовать WriteProcessMemory, то туда можно написать только адрес, который после перезапуска изменится (На скринах он 0012CB68).

18, 0, 18, 10 - это смещения, с помощью которых получаем адрес из поинтера. Как мне эти смещения использовать в Delphi?

Так выглядит основное окно программы:

[image: Value Changer]

Все манипуляции провожу над Cheat Engine Tutorial, тут как раз есть для этого пример #8:

[image: Cheta Engine Tutorial]